# Leak on const char *

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I have a leak from this code, but it is suppose to be autoreleased ?
Can any one explain why is it leaking ?

```
-(NSString*)tagName
{
    return @((const char*)_node->name);
}
```

**EDIT**
[image]

Thanks
Shani

Comment: What is _node->name ? What type is it ?

Comment: It looks like you are using `libxml2` (why not use `NSXMLDocument` or if you are targeting iOS, `NSXMLParser`?). The leak could be because you are not handling `libxml2`'s resources properly, e.g. with appropriate calls to `xmlFreeDoc`, `xmlFreeNode`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the posted code could leak is when there's no autorelease pool in place. You would see a console message if that would be the case.

If you want further help please provide more information about the leak, like an instruments screenshot or more information about how you are detecting the leak.